# Code snippet or shortcut to create a constructor in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, constructor, code-snippets, shortcut

What is the code snippet or shortcut for creating a constructor in Visual Studio?

Visual Studio 2010 and C#.

Answer (score 364, accepted):

Type "ctor" + <kbd>TAB</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> (hit the Tab key twice). This will create the default constructor for the class you are in:

```
public MyClass()
{

}
```

It seems that in some cases you will have to press <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice.

Comment: Not for me (typing `ctor` only shows the intellisense box, then I have to type `Tab` once to close that and once to "use" the snippet), but might be some setting somewhere...

Comment: In addition to this technique. If you make use of the class with a specific signature, you can refactor to get visual studio to generate the constructor for you.

Also if this is a default constructor and you are not doing anything with it, then it is assumed to be there by default.

Comment: Once or twice is a setting thing. I had this issue with a 1-letter-snippet and changed some (IntelliSense) settings to make 1 `Tab` work. `ctor` works for me with 1 hit though.

Comment: @Eve What setting did you change?

Comment: @Travis I'm translating: Go to Options → Text-Editor → C# → IntelliSense. Disable auto completion after 1 key. That's the key setting.

Comment: @Eve Hmm...thanks. Doesn't exist in my VS, but thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: @Travis How much of the path does exist in your VS ? I use VS 2010 Express and it's language is not English so you have to look around a bit and understand what I mean. In "IntelliSense" it's the very top option that must be disabled.

Comment: @Eve Turns out that ReSharper is interfering with the behavior, and that's where my issue is coming from. Thanks for your help, though. :)

Comment: @RayLoveless, I had the same issue that I was able to fix in VS2019. Go to Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense then change "Snippets Behavior" to "Always include snippets".

Answer (score 34):

If you want to see the list of all available snippets:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>X</kbd>.

Comment: This *is* actually an answer to the question as you can not only see the available snippets, but also invoke it: *"Visual C#"* → ctor → <Return> (and only slightly higher number of key presses, 9 instead of 5 (using only the keyboard)).

Comment: See also [Marleen Schilt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873702/code-snippet-or-shortcut-to-create-a-constructor-in-visual-studio/31404344#31404344).

Comment: It must be mentioned, that the correct snippet is Ctrl+K, Ctrl+X. Ctrl+K, X specifically doesn't work

Answer (score 18):

In case you want a constructor with properties, you need to do the following:

1. Place your cursor in any empty line in a class;
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to trigger the *Quick Actions* and *Refactorings* menu;

   [image: Refactoring menu]
3. Select *Generate constructor* from the drop-down menu;
4. Pick the members you want to include as constructor parameters. You can order them using the up and down arrows. Choose <kbd>OK</kbd>.

The constructor is created with the specified parameters.

[Generate a constructor in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-constructor?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 10):

Type `ctor`, and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice.

Answer (score 8):

For the full list of snippets (little bits of prefabricated code) press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
[Source from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165399(v=vs.100).aspx).
Works in Visual Studio 2013 with a C# project.

So how to make a constructor

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
2. Select Visual C#
3. Select ctor
4. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Update: You can also right-click in your code where you want the snippet, and select Insert Snippet from the right-click menu

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2010, if you type "ctor" (without the quotes), IntelliSense should load, showing you "ctor" in the list. Now press <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice, and you should have generated an empty constructor.

Answer (score 5):

If you use ReSharper, you can quickly generate constructors by typing:

- 'ctor' + <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (without parameters),
- 'ctorf' + <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (with parameters that initialize all fields) or
- 'ctorp' + <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (with parameters that initialize all properties).

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by many, "ctor" and double <kbd>TAB</kbd> works in Visual Studio 2017, but it only creates the constructor with none of the attributes.

To auto-generate with attributes (if there are any), just click on an empty line below them and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>. It'll display a small pop-up from which you can select the "Generate Constructor..." option.

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but OMG this saved me so much typing when doing object mapping. Thank you x1000.

Answer (score 3):

Simply type `ctor` then press <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Comment: Two TABs (instead of one) are necessary in at least one version of Visual Studio (possibly depending on configuration).

Answer (score 3):

Should you be interested in creating the 'ctor' or a similar class-name-injecting snippet from scratch, create a .snippet file in the C# snippets directory (for example `C:\VS2017\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\C#Snippets.snippet`) with this XML content:

```
<CodeSnippets>
    <CodeSnippet>
        <Header>
            <Title>ctor</Title>
            <Shortcut>ctor</Shortcut>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal Editable="false"><ID>classname</ID><Function>ClassName()</Function></Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code>
                <![CDATA[public $classname$($end$)
                {

                }]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

This snippet injects the current class name by way of calling C# code snippet function ClassName(), detailed on [this docs.microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippet-functions).

The end result of expanding this code snippet:

[image: 'ctor' snippet]

[image: Constructor end result]

Answer (score 3):

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Select "Generate Constructor"
3. Select required members

A parameterized constructor is generated with the selected members.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Visual Studio 2010, but in Visual Studio 2008 the code snippet is 'ctor'.

Comment: It is the same for vs-2008 and vs-2008, and I think is also the same for vs-2005 but not 100% sure.

Comment: I've used `ctor` forever in many versions of Visual Studio. I am contracting on a customer-provisioned laptop with VS 2019, and googled my way here because `ctor` is not working, even though I have now gone in and changed the "Snippets Behavior" (based on @ScubaSteve comment elsewhere on this question) - restarted V.S. and it's still not working

Answer (score 2):

Type *ctor*, and then press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Comment: Two TABs (instead of one) are necessary in at least one version of Visual Studio (possibly depending on configuration).

Answer (score 2):

Type `ctor` and <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

ََََََََََ

Comment: Two TABs (instead of one) are necessary in at least one version of Visual Studio (possibly depending on configuration).

Answer (score 2):

Type the name of any code snippet and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

To get code for properties you need to choose the correct option and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice because Visual Studio has more than one option which starts with 'prop', like 'prop', 'propa', and 'propdp'.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2017, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.

Comment: I tried and it's working.. Please read this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-constructor?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 1):

I have created some handy code snippets that'll create overloaded constructors as well. You're welcome to use them: https://github.com/ejbeaty/Power-Snippets

For example: 'ctor2' would create a constructor with two arguments and allow you to tab through them one by one like this:

```
public MyClass(ArgType argName, ArgType argName)
{

}
```