# Shortcut for creating constructor with variables (C# Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 C# you can, in a class, type `ctor` and then press <kbd>tab</kbd> and Visual Studio will create a constructor for that class for me. It is very convenient.

But is there a way to make Visual Studio create a constructor with all my variables, properties and so on?

For example,

```
public class User
{
    public String UserName { get; private set; }
}
```

And for this I want `ctor` + <kbd>tab</kbd> to make me a

```
public User(string UserName)
{
    this.UserName = UserName;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to create a constructor which violates .NET naming conventions?

Comment: @Markus - have you considered using the newer style object constructors in the generating client(s)?

Comment: @Garry Vass No, I don't even know what it is.

Comment: @Markus -> it's a lot cleaner than writing overloaded constructors in a lot of cases, read this:   How to: Initialize Objects by Using an Object Initializer (C# Programming Guide)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx

Comment: As a former java developer. I always look for outline pane to see methods in a pane(not in a combo-box) and source-> section in the context menu. I think Microsoft delegate these kind of jobs to 3rd parties, such as RSharper. If I were not see your question I would ask it.

Comment: @GarryVass: You cannot use object initializers with properties that have private setters. If you want to enforce the user of a data class to always set certain properties, there is no other way than to provide a constructor with the necessary parameters.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2012 you have to press Tab two times to get the constructor inserted.

Comment: cont' - Described in [in an answer to *Code snippet or shortcut to create a constructor in Visual Studio*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873702/code-snippet-or-shortcut-to-create-a-constructor-in-visual-studio/3873731#3873731).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Samuel Slade (telling me it's called code-snippets) I managed to find another Stack Overflow answer: *[Snippet code to create constructor in VS2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809677/snippet-code-to-create-constructor-in-vs2010-express)*

And it seems as **the answer is NO**, not without a plugin/extension.

Many refer to the [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) extension.

Answer (score 15):

You can sort of do this the other way around; if you start **without** the constructor or field, and try to use the non-existent constructor, you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to ask it to generate one for you, usage-first:

[image]

This compiler then generates something not too dissimilar:

```
public class User
{
    private string username;

    public User(string username)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

You can then fix this up manually if needed (perhaps using the inbuilt rename refactor, etc). But not **quite** what you wanted.

Comment: Well the reason that I want such a snippet is that I have a quite large number of properties, and it would speed up the work a great deal if I had one.

Answer (score 10):

I think what you are referring to is Code Snippets. You can write your own Code Snippets (they are written in XML). See [here](http://www.visualstudiotutor.com/2010/02/create-snippet-visual-studio-2010/) for a starting point.

You should also be able to edit existing Code Snippets (such as the `ctor` one). Refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5941d54.aspx) for some direction on this.

Note: Further Googling on Code Snippets will bring up more tutorials and references.

Comment: Thanks for the Code-Snippet, but it seems that the answer is no... It's not possible to create such advanced snippets.

Comment: The first link seems to be broken (not in DNS - domain does not exist).

Answer (score 2):

The "ctor" code snippet only creates a blank constructor, but does not use the existing attributes of the class in this constructor.

However, the latest versions of [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) enables you to choose the fields to be included in a constructor (like Eclipse does since a long time ago).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) the shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-constructors.html)

Comment: Sweet, I am actually using Resharper so that works for me!
(However I won't mark it as a solution since you have to have it, and I know a lot of people don't)

Comment: Sorry I used to use this shorcut before, but now I reinstall visual studio and this combination doesn't work, and before I have never installed Resharper.

Comment: Make sure Resharper Shortcuts is the one by default in your VS

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this with a snippet:

See *[Creating and Using IntelliSense Code Snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms165392(v=vs.100))* (MSDN)

Comment: Don't just link to solutions. If that link dies, so does your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, it is not possible to create snippets that are that intelligent.

There is a free Visual Studio add-in called [Comet](http://cometaddin.codeplex.com/) which can do what you want.

Comment: CodePlex has been shut down now. The link is still somewhat alive (*"download archive"*), but perhaps update it if Comet now has a new location, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ReSharper's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) *ctorf*.

This will allow you to create a constructor with generated arguments based on fields defined in the class.

Comment: I don't have my VS2017 to test, but are you sure this is not a ReSharper snippet?

Comment: yup. you're right. leaving it here because its good to know if you have resharper.