# Is there a shortcut for this type of constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor, visual-studio-2013

Let's say I have an class `Activity` whose constructor's sole purpose is to assign the passed arguments to the properties for this instance:

```
class Activity
{
 string name;
 int participantCount;
 bool inProgress;

 public Activity(string name,int participantCount,bool inProgress)
 {
  this.name=name;
  this.participantCount=participantCount;
  this.inProgress=inProgress;
 }
}
```

I use this pattern of constructor very frequently in my applications, so, assuming that this is an acceptable programming practice, I'm wondering if there is some kind of shortcut in Visual Studio for generating it, or a way of accomplishing the same effect with less code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortcut for creating constructor with variables (C# VS2010)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893979/shortcut-for-creating-constructor-with-variables-c-vs2010)

Comment: Resharper is great for this sort of thing.

Comment: This is a good question but I want to point out probably an oversight in your part that an `Object` is an instance of a `Class`. In this case `Activity` (is not an Object as you mentioned) is a class and instance of it would be an object. I am not trying to nitpicked but just want to be sure that newbie who will be reading your question will not be unnecessarily confuse.

Comment: @Edper, thanks, I will edit to make that clearer.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter, I think this isn't a duplicate because I'm working with VS2013 and was hoping that either it has a feature that previous VS versions don't have, or maybe that a VS plugin has surfaced in the last two years since that answer was posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio does not have any shortcuts for this, but [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does (if you are programming .NET and not using R#, you are wasting a lot of time)

When you generate a constructor using R#, you'll be asked to specify properties that should be initialized by it.

See http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Type_Constructors.html

Answer (score 4):

I agree, it would be very helpful to have a shortcut for this. TypeScript does, and it's very nice. Unfortunately, C# 5.0 doesn't have anything like this. Fortunately, it's coming - or something like it - in C# 6.0.

The current proposed syntax looks something like this:

```
public class Point(int x, int y) {
    public int x, y;
}
```

I'm not sure I like that syntax - I'd prefer something like how TS does it:

```
public class Point(public int x, private int y) { }
```

But what I want is probably irrelevant :-).

See http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated.

Comment: This is speculation, not an actual confirmed feature.

Comment: Somewhere in-between, actually. It's originally from Mads Torgersen, and was presented at an official MS developer's conference - see http://adamralph.com/2013/12/06/ndc-diary-day-3/#more. But you're correct that the syntax has probably not been finalized, and it's at least conceivable that it won't make it in at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature in Resharper that does this.

[Generating Type Constructors](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Type_Constructors.html)