# Can VS 2012 generate a class constructor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Can VS 2012 professional generate a class constructor without any addons?

I can't believe I can't find the option to do this, and if it can't do it, it truly is a conspiracy :)

I have my class defined:

```
public class User
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Now is there a shortcut that will generate the constructor, `toString()` method etc?

Comment: Generate as in, automatically?

Comment: Re-sharper can do it... but visual studio has no such option.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yes, I have updated my question to clarify what I am asking.

Comment: @Hypenate Yes I know resharper can do it, but vs.net is so advanced and $ I am shocked it doesn't have basic code generation w/o any addons.

Comment: there are a *few* code generation shortcuts i know of and use often.  All of which you hit tab after: ctor (contructor), prop, propg... there are many more but those are the ones i use on the regular

Comment: @Kritner Those are called *snippets* and are probably the best choice here.

Comment: ahh snippets neat.  Yeah found a list of them here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Kritner it just created an empty constructor for me, no option to init all the properties?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortcut for creating constructor with variables (C# VS2010)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893979/shortcut-for-creating-constructor-with-variables-c-vs2010)

Answer (score 3):

If you need a default constructor then there is a [code snippet `ctor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat(v=vs.90).aspx) for it.

---

But if you need a constructor with parameters then in you code write:

```
User user = new User(2, "Name");
```

This will be an error, since there is no constructor with two parameters, but you will get a blue under line if you hover your mouse over `User` in `new User`. Click on that or put your cursor on `User` and press `Ctrl + .` It will give you an option to generate constructor like:

[image]

That will give you a constructor with fields like:

```
public class User
{
    private int p1;
    private string p2;

    public User(int p1, string p2)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have to go in and remove `p1`, `p2` and point to `Id`, `Name` and also rename parameters in constructor. That is probably the best you can do with **only** Visual studio.

See: [Generate From Usage - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409796(v=vs.100).aspx) *(thanks to @Peter Ritchie)*

---

Consider installing Re-Sharper it has much better option for [generating not only constructor](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Type_Constructors.html) but other very helpful code.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, that is very useful link.

Comment: Thanks but it is as if the designs of vs.net don't actually code.  I don't want to write out that line just to generate a constructor.  Sure its nice to have that option also, but while I am creating a class I want to generate a full constructor!

Comment: Consider installing Resharper?  Tell that to my boss who has to pay $xxx for it lol.

Comment: @publicstatic, Not directly related but show your boss [The Programmer's Bill of Rights - Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-programmers-bill-of-rights/) and think about switching companies then :P

Comment: @Habib are you hiring?  :)   My boss may show me the door.

Answer (score 0):

[snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx) are built in and you can add your own. ctor will make the constructor, I don't think there is anything for ToString, though you can just type override, pick it from the list and it will stub it out.

Answer (score -1):

"ctor" snippet generates a constructor, but without parameters. To get them, you should unfortunately use (free or not) addons. This question has been already discussed, see [Shortcut for creating constructor with variables (C# VS2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893979/shortcut-for-creating-constructor-with-variables-c-vs2010) for example.

I think there is no direct mean to generate a paramerized constructor in a bare Visual Studio.

Edit : I should probably have added after my last sentence "... which strictly applies to properties and fields currently defined in class". But yes, following Peter's advice it is possible to generate a kind of parameterized constructor.

Comment: Another question details that it *is* possible, and it's documented for as far back as 2010 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409796(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @PeterRitchie Not agree. "Generate for usage" is not strictly "Generate in place constructor" : the parameters order and names would not match with existing props and fields in class ! It's nice to mention it since it can be helpful, but this solution is far to be as efficient as R# ctor generation for example.

Comment: And "ctor" was mentioned. OP shows us some fields present in class so I guessed his goal was to generate a constructor against them...